# User defined cron job iis server

Tags: php, windows, iis, cron, cron-task

I want to execute a script at user defined day and time. I have read about cron jobs. Issue is that in cron job we have to define dtime. I also have read [Create a cron job with user define dtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28293365/create-a-cron-job-with-user-define-dtime)

Where/How to execute `shell_exec($cmd);` command
I am using IIS server.

Comment: Why downvoted? If you have answer then please help.

Answer (score 0):

I have used a scheduled task to send entries in my outgoing mail table.

The `action` calls the php executable;
`"C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.3\php.exe"`

Then an argument with a `-f` set calls the script;
`-f C:\inetpub\wwwroot\xxx\tools\send-mail.php`

You could also look at creating each as a task. PHP however, wont help you with this. See [c# creating scheduled tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394806/creating-scheduled-tasks).

Comment: I don't want server to look after every 5 minutes.

Comment: just modify the triggers or does the user defined time change?

Comment: Yes it can change

Comment: You could store the time in DB or file, then get the script to read that time and if less than or near current execute the command, call the script at a set interval and get it to check. If it needs to be instant, I'm not sure how or if you could modify the scheduled task dependent on just php interactions

Comment: I am using PHP.